# How to create 2 new column in DataFrame based on the highest values in rest of column with appropriate prefix in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, aggregate

I have Pandas DataFrame like below (I can add that my DataFrame is definitely bigger, so I need to do below aggregation only for selected columns):

```
ID   | COUNT_COL_A | COUNT_COL_B | SUM_COL_A | SUM_COL_B
-----|-------------|-------------|-----------|------------
111  | 10          | 10          | 320       | 120
222  | 15          | 80          | 500       | 500
333  | 0           | 0           | 110       | 350
444  | 20          | 5           | 0         | 0
555  | 0           | 0           | 0         | 0
666  | 10          | 20          | 30        | 50
```

Requirements:

- I need to create new column "TOP_COUNT" where will be name of column (COUNT_COL_A or COUNT_COL_B) with the highest value per each ID,

  - if some ID has same values in both "COUNT_" columns take to "TOP_COUNT" column name which has higher value in its counterpart with prefix SUM_ (SUM_COL_A or SUM_COL_B)
- I need to create new column "TOP_SUM" where will be name of column (SUM_COL_A or SUM_COL_B) with the highest value per each ID,

  - if some ID has same values in both "SUM_" columns take to "TOP_SUM" column name which has higher value in its counterpart with prefix COUNT_ (COUNT_COL_A or COUNT_COL_B)
- If there is 0 in both columns with prefix COUNT_ then give NaN in column TOP_COUNT
- If there is 0 in both columns with prefix SUM_ then give NaN in column TOP_SUM

Desire output:

```
ID   | COUNT_COL_A | COUNT_COL_B | SUM_COL_A | SUM_COL_B  | TOP_COUNT   | TOP_SUM
-----|-------------|-------------|-----------|------------|-------------|---------
111  | 10          | 10          | 320       | 120        | COUNT_COL_A | SUM_COL_A 
222  | 15          | 80          | 500       | 500        | COUNT_COL_B | SUM_COL_B  
333  | 0           | 0           | 110       | 350        | NaN         | SUM_COL_B  
444  | 20          | 5           | 0         | 0          | COUNT_COL_A | NaN
555  | 0           | 0           | 0         | 0          | NaN         | NaN
666  | 10          | 20          | 60        | 50         | COUNT_COL_B | SUM_COL_A
```

How can i do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idxmax` function as follows:

```
df['TOP_COUNT'] = df[['COUNT_COL_A' , 'COUNT_COL_B']].idxmax(axis="columns")
df['TOP_SUM'] = df[[' SUM_COL_A','SUM_COL_B']].idxmax(axis="columns")

df.loc[(df[['COUNT_COL_A' , 'COUNT_COL_B']]==0).all(axis=1), 'TOP_COUNT'] = pd.NA
df.loc[(df[['SUM_COL_A','SUM_COL_B']]==0).all(axis=1), 'TOP_SUM'] = pd.NA
```

Comment: MSS it is not a good answer for my question, because you only select highest value per ID, you do not take into consideration prefix of columns and fact, that for example: if some ID has same values in both "SUM_" columns take to "TOP_SUM" column name which has higher value in its counterpart with prefix COUNT_ (COUNT_COL_A or COUNT_COL_B)

Comment: Let me update the answer

Comment: Ok, MSS plaese :)

Comment: It works perfcet! One more question MSS, if I can, could you also add column TOP_COUNT_2 and TOP_SUM_2 where will be mentioned after the decimal point column names if values in columns with the same prefix are same? for example TOP_COUNT_2 for ID = 111 will be COUNT_COL_A, COUNT_COL_B ?

Comment: Ask another question for it

Comment: MSS, I gave you best answer here because it works percet, I asked also new quesion about case I mention in my comment, could you check it here, please?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180687/how-to-create-new-columns-with-name-of-columns-with-the-highest-value-per-id-me